# Uniqueness of attribute value in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Currently I have this XML file

```
<Vehicles>
    <Car id="0" name="Kia" />
    <Car id="1" name="Opel"/>

    <Plane id="0" name="Airbus"/>
    <Plane id="1" name="Boeing" />
</Vehicles>
```

and schema for it:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="VehicleType">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Vehicles">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Car" type="VehicleType" />
            <xs:element name="Plane" type="VehicleType" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="CarIdsMustBeUnique">
        <xs:selector xpath="Car" />
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>

    <xs:unique name="PlaneIdsMustBeUnique">
        <xs:selector xpath="Plane" />
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>

</xs:element>
```

As you can see I want id of cars and planes to be unique, but I have to write two unique blocks to achieve it. Can I minimize code duplicate and join xs:unique stament in one with more complex selector? Because if I will add another vehicle (trains for example) I will force to write very simmilar unique block.

I am to lazy to write some much unique block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there is a car with @id=0 and also a plane with @id=0. That means there are two separate sets of unique IDs, one set for cars and one for planes, and therefore there must be two separate unique constraints. If id's of all vehicles had to be unique, regardless of the vehicle type, then you would be able to combine the constraints into one.

Comment: Yes you right for second case I can use <xs:selector xpath="Plane|Car" /> selector.